# How to detect where is ROLLBACK TRAN?

Tags: c++, sql-server, visual-c++, oledb

I have a c++->OLEDB->SQL Server application.
It works fine but one place:
I see in SQL Profiler:

```
RPC Completed: exec myproc -- its OK
SQL:BatchStarting: IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRAN
SQL:BatchCompleted: IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Naturally, after this roll back the next call is failed etc.
But I did not find this in the c++ code
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRAN

How to find it? What statement can generate it?

Comment: this code? as far as I know, is typical for stored procedures

Comment: The conditional rollback should not cause the next call to fail. If it's not executed by your code, maybe it's executed by connection pooling to clean up the connection prior to reuse.

Comment: I have added the column ObjectName to profile and this field is empty on these statements. I.e.  in the proc no these stmts, and it is still unclear for me where it is called. But calling App name  is my app.

Comment: @DanGuzman yes, you are right, but this Rollback rolled back some inserts and the next call cannot find the row - so failed.

Comment: @ZedZip, that symptom suggests a transaction was started and never committed. Do you have an explicit `BEGIN TRAN` in the code or proc? Is the `IMPLICIT TRANSACTIONS` session setting ON? Either requires a `COMMIT`.

Comment: @ZedZip is this whole output of what profiler shows? If not, could you please run the app again and post the complete output?

Comment: @DanGuzman, Yes, the app executes  pSession->StartTransaction();
exec p1; exec p2;
pSession->Commit(); but after it I see in the profiler IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRAN and then the app execs p3 but it failed :  the record does not exist (it was rolled back),  I cannot find the place in the app where this rollback called.

Comment: @ZedZip, do you execute `Abort()` somewhere in the code?

Comment: @DanGuzman yes, I do. I set breakpoints on every session->Abort() but did not reach them and in profiler I see the rollback. Puzzle....